# does print function can ignore result of return on function?

Tags: python, function

I'm studying the variable scope of function of python
and I have some questions :D

This is code that I'm studying

---

```
#global code
num1 = 10
num2 = 30

def test(num1, num2):
    print(num1, num2)
    return num1 + num2

test(30, 40)
print(num1, num2)
```

---

and result is

```
30 40 #result of print(num1, num2) on test function
10 30 #result of print(num1, num2)
```

I know that those variables(num1, num2) are different(one is global and the other one is local), but I wonder why there is no result of the test function's return.

plz help me to understand TT

Comment: you need to print it `print(test(30, 40))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right about `local` and `global` variables. To get result of your function you need to do that

```
num1 = 10
num2 = 30

def test(num1, num2):
    print(num1, num2)
    return num1 + num2

result_of_test = test(30, 40)
print(result_of_test)
print(num1, num2)
```

So you need to assign `return` result of your function to variable. And then print it.

Comment: Thx a lot :D  It really helped me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the return value is not assigned or used in anything when you call it like `test(30, 40)`. Stuff will only be printed to the output if you explicitly tell it to be with `print()`.

For example, if you do `print(test(30, 40))`, the return value will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, print the function call.

```
num1 = 10
num2 = 30

def test(num1, num2):
    print(num1, num2)
    return num1 + num2

print(test(30,40)) #change your code to this
print(num1, num2)
```

Return statements aren't printed automatically when you call the function, they are just returned and stored in variable if there is one.